# Grails apps in docker, installation of spring-security plugins?

Tags: docker, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

A newbie question regarding both Grails app running in Docker, and spring-security-ldap 2.0.1 plugin.

Currently I am running a local Grails apps (not in Docker), installation of  spring-security-ldap 2.0.1 is pretty simple with mainly a added line in BuildConfig.groovy:
    plugins {
        compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0.1"
    }

After implemented the necessary user details and mapping classes, the first time running the Grails app, the installation of spring-security-ldap is automatically carried out and install a bunch of stuff under the 
//src/target/work/plugins/spring-security-ldap-2.0.1/ folder, these are the things that drive the Ldap login support I supposed.

Now, if I were to move my Grails App into a docker container, what is the proper way to get this plugin installation done? Where to specify the resolution and installation of the plugin?

**[Update 20180425]**

NVM, I just tried it with my changed codes (specifying the LDAP plugins in BuildConfig.groovy), rebuilt the Docker images, and executed it and I can now see the auth login page. That means the plugin had been successfully resolved from external repo and built into the Docker image!

The problem now is, I am not able to log in with the test users:
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: localhost:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]

It has to be about the opening the Docker in/out ports for my local OpenLdap. I will read a bit on Docker documentation for this.

Comment: A @alchn What Grails version are you using?

Comment: Why is this a problem (do you actually have a problem, then please state it)?  Do you want to dockerize your development or running the applicaton?

Comment: Plugins are "resolved" and "installed" at build time.  So if your build is local but you run the built app in a container, there's nothing extra to do.  If you build in a container, then the container needs internet access so the build can find the repositories needed for the build (including your plugin).  The only real change may be in how you deliver configuration and secrets to the application since you probably don't want that info to reside in the Docker image. `ENVIRONMENT` variables are one way to do it.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed I am using Grails 2.4.4.

Comment: @cfrick Yes I want to dockerize my the Grails app, together with the ldap plugin.

Comment: @npskirk The app war would be build in docker. My doubt is, the ldap plugin are auto installed in the '/target/work/plugins' folder, so it won't be pulled into the docker image. I am unsure but assuming, during Docker build time, it would pull the plugin from external repo again (the external access is already working for other dependencies) and put it into '/target', make into war, all in the docker environment. I am not sure where/how do I specify Docker config that execute this line in my BuildConfig.groovy: plugins { compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0.1" } as if it is in my local.

Comment: To put things in context, this particular Grails app is already up running in QA and Prod on Docker, just without the LDAP integration yet. My task is to add LDAP integration to this app. In my local, I had added the spring security LDAP plugin and done the implementation. I am just wondering how to move/deploy the changes (mostly the plugin part) into a Dockerized environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create a `war` file using `grails war`. It will automatically add all the dependencies in the war file including `spring-security-ldap`. You don't have to worry about anything regarding dependency injection.

Afterward, you can follow these steps to create and run a docker image:

### A) Creating Dockerfile

Create a file named `Dockerfile` in your project directory with the following content:

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.86-jre7
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/bin
COPY <path/to/your-war-file> /usr/local/tomcat/webapp/<application-name>.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

### B) Creating an Image

Simply execute `docker build -t <image name>:<image version> .` This will create a docker image in your local docker engine.

### C) Running the Container

Finally, start your application by executing `docker run -p <port you wanna bind>:8080 <image name>:<image version>`

If everything goes right, you can now access your application on the port you bound in `docker run ..` command.

### Update

To answer your updated question, when you access `localhost` inside a container, it doesn't resolve to the localhost of the docker host machine. It resolves to the container itself. So, if you have something running on the host machine (OpenLDAP on port 389 in this case), you'll have to access this by using the IP of the host machine.

A better solution, in this case, is to run [OpenLDAP in docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/osixia/openldap/) container also. That way, you can access OpenLDAP with its hostname and you won't have to change the IP if it changes.

Comment: "Assuming a Grails 3.x application..." - The question mentions `BuildConfig.groovy` and `...src/target/work/plugins/...`.  That isn't a Grails 3 app.

Comment: Updated the answer for grails 2.4.4. Thank you for notifying.

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. Actually building of the war need to be inside of the Docker build, rather than on my local first and copy into Docker, this is to follow the build flow in our QA/Prod environment. But anyhow (please refer to my updated section in Q ) I had gotten this part working, that the LDAP plugin is running from the Grails app from within the container already. Only problem remaining now is that it can't talk/query my OpenLDAP at port 389, so I will need another in/out port bounding for my OpenLdap service. I need to read up Docker documentation for that...

Comment: I updated the answer to your question update. Let me know if you need more detail and/or example. @alchn

Comment: @SaqibAhmed "A better solution, in this case, is to run OpenLDAP in docker container also." <--- Unfortunately I can't do that, bcos eventually the Grails Apps is gonna talk to our corporate existing LDAP server, which would not be inside Docker.  I am just temporarily using a local OpenLdap for development purpose.

Comment: The existing corporate LDAP will/should have a static IP. In that case, you'll hardcode that static IP so it won't cause any problem. `OpenLDAP` in docker is only required in testing.